# Regexes Strip all link except link containing xxx word

Tags: regex

I want to remove all  tag link from my site, except link containing xxx word in it.

Example:

```
<a class="happy" href="https://example.com/good-day/" rel="nofollo">happy day</a>
```

if the above code found, let it be replace with just text **happy day**

now if the below code if found and the link contain **xxx** in it, let it just leave it the way it is.

```
<a class="happy" href="https://example.com/good-day-xxx-now/" rel="nofollo">happy day</a>
```

so far the link contain **xxx** in it let it NOT be replace just just text.

I have tried the below regexes but it replaces all the content to just text

```
</?a(|\s+[^>]+)>
```

I TRIED TO USE THIS `</?a(|\s+[^>]+^(?!.*xxx).*$)>` but i still could not achieve what i was looking for.

Comment: You'd better avoid using regex to parse HTML, if you used an HTML parser you'd just have to check if the href attribute contains the 'xxx' fixed string and you'd be able to remove the whole link easily.

Comment: I just need it, i hope i could find solution.

Comment: the above regexes you posted did not work well, the link that was suppose to be replace with just plain text, is just deleted entirely, i.e it deletes the **happy day** instead of replacing it to just text

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/f39hbj/2

Comment: thanks so much, the above one you posted before works best, after i removed **/** from the code. here is the both modified version, I have integrated more text to it.

`<a[^>]*href="(?:(?!\.mp3|\/tag\/)[^"])*"[^>]*(?:>|>[^<]*</a>)`



`<a[^>]*href="(?:(?!\.mp3|coco)[^"])*"[^>]*>([^<]*)<\/a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a[^>]*href="(?:(?!\.mp3|\/tag\/)[^"])*"[^>]*(?:>|>[^<]*</a>)



<a[^>]*href="(?:(?!\.mp3|coco)[^"])*"[^>]*>([^<]*)<\/a>
```

credit goes to: @Aaron